# VS code is not showing suggestions

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I autocomplete an HTML attribute (my cursor is now inside ""), the VS code does not display any suggestions for attribute values. However, if I manually delete quotes ("") and type quotes (""), it suddenly displays suggestions. Is there any way to solve this problem?

A suggestion to change any settings in vscode or an extension that could solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through this same situation before I fix it by downloading extension which is specific to your programming language .

Before doing that please check if auto detect is working on VS Code correctly . If it not fix it and check if the problem is solved .

Comment: I'm using HTML, which has no official extension. However, if you know of any useful extensions, you are welcome to suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion list of Basic completion appears when you press the default Visual Studio IntelliSense shortcut Ctrl+Space

Comment: It works, but is there an automatic solution? (without pressing any key)